# Acceleration $v = sin (100t^2+2)$.?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, calculus

> The relationship between the velocity of the top of a birds wings with time before takeoff is modelled by $v = sin (100t^2+2)$. What is the acceleration after 0.5 seconds?

Acceleration is the rate change of velocity. Hence I took the derivative of $sin (100t^2+2)$ at the $t=0.5$. On my calculator, my answer was 1.55. However, when converting to radians my calculator got the correct answer. $-29.2$. Why is it nessecary to convert to radians?

Comment: Derivatives and integrals must always be in radians

Comment: @BioPhysicist. How do we know that the person who derived the original equation for the velocity had the insight to use radians just in case someone decided to integrate or differentiate the equation? In other words, the "2" could be in degrees. If someone wanted to integrate or differentiate, that person would need to convert the 2 degrees (and 100 deg/sec^2) to radians in order to follow your suggestion. In other words, the question is poorly phrased since it does not give the units, in my opinion. The OP is correct in being confused (assuming no details were left out).

Comment: @JohnHoltz Thanks for your reply, but it looks like you have pulled way more out of my comment beyond what I said. I didn't say the question couldn't have been given in terms of degrees, and I didn't say the OP shouldn't be confused. I'll gladly address what I said, but hopefully other things won't be attributed to me that wasn't said